# „Anywhere“ und „somewhere“ auseinanderhalten

Tags: meaning

Im Deutschen gibt es das Wort *irgendwo,* das sowohl *anywhere* als auch *somewhere* bedeuten kann.

Kennt die deutsche Sprache eine Möglichkeit, diese beiden Bedeutungen auseinanderzuhalten, damit klar ist, von welcher die Rede ist?

Es ist schwierig, ein gutes Beispiel zu finden, aber ich versuche es.

> I could put it somewhere. → I’m not sure whether I put at all.
>   I could put it anywhere. → I don’t know where to put it.

Das Schwerpunkt dieser Frage ist aber kein konkreter Fall sondern das Streben, die Konzepte *at **some** place/time/etc.* und *at **any** place* auseinanderzuahlten; d.h. das **some** und **any** zu betonen.

Vgl. russisch *где-либо/где-нибудь* und *где-то*, polnisch *gdzie**ś*** und *gdzie**kolwiek***.

Answer (score 6):

Vielleicht können diese Beispiele auch helfen:

> Free to cook anytime, anywhere.        Die Freiheit, jederzeit zu kochen, überall.
> Free to cook sometimes, somewhere.     Frei, manchmal, irgendwo zu kochen.
>
> Ich möchte nicht irgend**wo** arbeiten.              I do not want to work somewhere.
> Ich möchte nirgendwo (überall nicht) arbeiten.   I do not want to work anywhere.

Comment: Das sind eigentlich keine *Beispiele*, sondern eine ziemlich gute Antwort.

Answer (score 5):

You could translate "somewhere" as "irgendwo" and "anywhere" as "überall" in this case:

> I could put it somewhere. = Ich könnte es irgendwo hinlegen.
>
> I could put it anywhere. = Ich könnte es überall hinlegen.

Answer (score 2):

Für "anywhere" gibt es auch den umgangssprachlichen Ausdruck "sonst wo". Zum Beispiel:

> I could put it anywhere ⇒ "Ich kann's eigentlich sonst wo hinlegen."

Quelle: https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/sonst

Answer (score 1):

Ich kann mir keine Übersetzung der einzelnen Worte "somewhere" und "anywhere" vorstellen, mit der dieser Unterschied im Deutschen ausgedrückt werden könnte.

In geschriebener Sprache könnte man eine Erklärung hinzufügen, ähnlich wie die, die du schon vorgeschlagen hast. Als Alternative könnte man den Satz etwas unformulieren, um eindeutig klar zu machen, was man sagen will:

> I could put it somewhere:
>
> - Ich weiß nicht, ob ich es irgendwo hinlege
>
> I could put it anywhere:
>
> - Ich weiß nicht, wo ich es hinlegen werde

Anstatt "Ich weiß nicht", könnte man, je nach Zusammenhang, auch sagen:

- Ich kann mir aussuchen, ...
- Es ist noch nicht klar, ...
- Es ist egal, ...
- Ich bin nicht sicher, ...
- Es steht mir frei, ...

In jedem Fall wird damit klar, dass die Wahl einmal darin besteht, **"ob"** man es irgendwo hin legt, und im anderen Fall, **"wo"** man es hinlegen wird.

---

Eine andere Möglichkeit könnte sein, "anywhere" nicht mit "irgendwo", sondern mit "überall" zu übersetzen (auch wenn man wortwoörtlich eher "everywhere" bedeutet), um klar zu machen, dass der *Ort* beliebg ist, aber nicht *ob* man es tut oder nicht. Da das etwas umgangssprachlich klingt, ist es aber nicht in jedem Fall anwendbar.

---

In gesprochener Sprache kann man einen Hinweis auf die Bedeutung geben, indem man bestimmte Worte betont:

> I could put it somewhere:
>
> - Ich könnte das <sub>irgendwo</sub> **hin** legen
>
> I could put it anywhere:
>
> - Ich könnte das **irgend**wo <sub>hin</sub> legen

Aber das ist sehr subtil, und sollte nur verwendet werden, wenn die Gefahr für Mißverständnisse nicht so groß ist.

Comment: Die Frage wurde auf Deutsch gestellt. Es wäre hilfreich, die Antwort in derselben Sprache zu verfassen.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Das ist etwas heikel, da die Antwort schon sehr alt ist, und geupvoted wurde - da sollte man größere Änderungen IMHO vermeiden. Aber ich habe versucht es bedeutungserhaltend zu übersetzen, werde demnächst Antworten in der gleichen Sprache wie die Frage schreiben, und ... diesen Kommentar später löschen,...